# C# импорт из EXCEL не загружает первую ячейку

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

все достало... любил я это дело очень долго. В программе происходит выбор одного либо нескольких документов формата excel с последующей загрузкой в datagridview, после получившиеся строки и ячейки обрабатываются внутренними механизмами, но тут попался один файл... который прибит гвоздями и изменять его никакой поставщик не хочет... суть проблемы в том, что если первая ячейка имеет "перенос текста", то ячейка 1:1 не загружается в datagridview.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] если же ячейка не имеет переноса текста, то загрузка происходит как нужно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
аналогичная ситуация происходит, если этот excel файл открыт ( первая ячейка отображается в DGV ) иначе этой ячейки нет... прикладываю кусок кода кнопки загрузки excel я  а так же этот чертов файл.... может кто сталкивался с таким багом. версию excel я не возможно поднять...
[excel файл](https://yadi.sk/i/yVQY1WbA5MTnSg)

```
 public void down()// загрузка
    {

        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = true;
        dialog.Filter = "Файл Excel|*.xlsx;*.xls;";
        try
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] selectedFiles = dialog.SafeFileNames;
                string[] filePaths = dialog.FileNames;


                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                foreach (string file1 in (string[])dialog.FileNames)
               
                {

                    String constr = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", file1);
                    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    myConnection.Open();

                    DataTable spreadSheetData = myConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string sheetName = "";
                    OleDbCommand onlineConnection;
                    OleDbDataAdapter theDataAdapter;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in spreadSheetData.Rows)
                    {
                        sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        sheetName = sheetName.Replace("'", "");
                        if (sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                        {
                            onlineConnection = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "A1:Y100"+"]", myConnection);
                            theDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(onlineConnection);
                            dt.TableName = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.TableName)) ? sheetName : dt.TableName;
                            theDataAdapter.Fill(dt);


                        }
                    }
                   
                    myConnection.Close();

                }


                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];



                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
                }


            }
        }

        catch
            (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message, "Ошибка при считывании excel файла"); }
    }
```

Comment: А если выгрузить в CSV? Например запускаете `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, грузите в него `xls`, и командуете ему "Сохранить как CSV", потом CSV-шку можно будет молниеносно пережевать с помощью какого-нибудь CSVHelper. В чем преимущество OLE DB подхода здесь перед костылем, что я выше предложил? :) У вас SharePoint, редактирование одного файла несколькими пользователями одновременно? Бороться с 2007 Excel в 2020 году - такое, я бы просто свел взаимодействие с ним к минимуму.

Comment: @peter хочется малой кровью обойтись и не ворошить проект из 2010 года для компании из 2007 ... Но идея не плохая с CSV